# Unable to add comments on closed questions or their answers in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app, closed-questions

In the Android App, if a question is closed, I won't be able to leave comments on either the question or any of its answers. There are simply no "Add Comment" buttons available *anywhere* if the question is closed.

See the screenshot below. The comment adding interface is simply removed on closed questions and their answers — no Reply button in the toolbar, and no Add Comment button under the question.

> [image: comments]

Occurs on Android app v1.0.50 and v1.0.51, on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

Comment: Yep I'm noticing the same problem.

Comment: Can you add comments for the answers on closed question? Also worth to mention this affects only the android app (can add comments on closed questions from iOS app) so it's not API bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I'm unable to comment on answers too.

Comment: Running android 4.4.4 on moto g same problem here. Thanks for pointing out duplicate status @ShadowWizard

Comment: @CRags yeah, it is not related to specific device, it's a bug in the app itself and the way it works with the API. (e.g. maybe it thinks closed is locked thus not letting users to comment)

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Still a problem as of 1.0.60

Comment: @ChrisForrence (and others) are you still experiencing this? We switched over to using logic from the API rather than on the client-side for this a long time ago, I'm not able to recreate it locally but that may be due to me being a mod.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Not sure; I'll try to verify it later today.

Comment: @ChrisForrence thank you! You can test it easily by searching for `closed:1` in the app.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I have just managed to add comments to a closed question and its answer. All seems well here. You fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I fixed this last October but forgot to update this post! We now use a new parameter `can_comment` to determine if you can actually comment on a post or not, rather than trying to do way too many logical operations on the client side that result in bugs like this.